# How to include proper zurb-foundation js files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I want to include js files as this document explained.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

How can I include js file to rails project in place of normal way like `<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>`?

I'm using Rails4 and `gem 'zurb-foundation'.

Comment: read this [railscasts #417 foundation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've read it once before the article but I read through it again, and it seems to be that all js files are already included.